# Changing "<a>" to "<span>" on screen resize with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to replace an `a` tag in my `nav` with a `span` tag if the browser is resized below a certain `width`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">one</a></li>
                <li><a href="">two</a></li>
            </ul>  
        </li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```js
$( window ).on('load resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 478) {
        $('.menu-main-menu-container ul li:nth-child(2) a').first().replaceWith(function() {
            return $('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
        });
    } 
});
```

Right now, everything works on load. If I resize the browser than all `a` tags are replaced with `span` tags.

Only the first `a` tag in the second `li` tag needs to be replaced with a `span` tag.

Comment: That's a bad idea; `resize` events can happen quite frequently.  What are you trying to do? You should use media queries.

Comment: Media queries will be the best way

Comment: You could have two elements, one being a span and the other an anchor. Hide one and show the other in one resolution, and vice versa via media query. Using jQuery to manipulate the dom in this fashion is certainly doable, but probably should be avoided.

Comment: What's the reason for change an `a` to a `span` ... to make it non clickable? ... and what should happen when resized back to a wider screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your `resize()` function. Once the treshhold of 478px is reached, the correct `a` will be replaced. If you are now continue to resize the next `a` will match your selector because the first one is a `span` now.

If you know your HTML-structure is not dynamic and stays like this you can use the immediate child selector `>`:

```
$('.menu-main-menu-container > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a:first').replaceWith(function() {
     return $('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6ymfu48c/1/)

Comment: Oh duh, ok yeah that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, but I would considering what @DrewKennedy wrote in his comment and go with media-queries.

Answer (score 2):

you are targetting incorrectly your `li`, use `eq()` and you can use `:first` for `a`

> That's selecting the li in the child ul. I don't need that. I need the
>   first two to changed to two

then you have to use the direct child `>` just to target the `a` inside the  the 2nd  `li` and not the child `ul`

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 478) {
    $('.menu-main-menu-container ul > li:eq(1) >  a:first').replaceWith(function() {
      return $('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  background: red;
  display: block
}
a {
  background: green;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">two</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">one</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">two</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to target the second ul though. I want to the target the second li in the main ul, not the child ul.

Comment: That's selecting the li in the child ul. I don't need that. I need the first <a href="">two</a> to changed to <span>two</span>

Comment: copy that, you have to be more specific in your question at first

Comment: My bad, I have "Only the first "a" tag in the second "li" tag" but I will be more clear the next time. If I use $('.menu-main-menu-container ul  li:eq(1) a:first') than the same problem occurs. Everything works on load but resizing changes all "a" tags to "span" tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('.menu-main-menu-container ul li:eq(2) a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
});
```